# HBase configuration

Tags: windows, hbase, windowserror

I'm new in HBase and I am trying to install and configure it in Windows following the  instructions mentioned on the Hbase site:

http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html

However I've tried several times to follow all the instructions but never succeed when I run the command: `./bin/start-hbase.sh`

The last error that appeared me was:

```
Pedro@pedrocunha /usr/local/hbase-1.0.1
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-1.0.0/logs/hbase-Pedro-master-pedrocunha.out
cat: C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-1.0.0/conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
cat: C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-1.0.0/conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
```

The version of Hbase I am using is 1.0.1. 
Does anyone know if these instructions are correct? I have to change so that everything works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the HBASE_HOME property correctly to the HBASE installation directory and check

set HBASE_HOME=/PATH/TO/HBASE